# Str_replace using shortcode with multiple changes

Tags: shortcode, array

I am using a feed importer plugin which gives the option to use a short code in case I need to change data (in this case data for a custom field) on import, using for example:

```
    [str_replace('This','that',{feedfield})]
```

But how do I use this when I have more to change? Because it's a shortcode I can't use an array like:

```
    $a = 'this', 'another this';
    $b = 'that', 'another that';
    echo str_replace($a, $b, get_post_meta($post->ID, 'feedfield', true));
```

Can anyone enlighten my lack of knowledge?

Comment: without knowing what plugin this is, how can we help you? sounds like modifying it to accept an array somehow (list of comma separated terms?) that you might find enlightenment.

Comment: The plugin is not important I think? 
Question is how to use an array or multiple entries in a shortcode function (within brackets)
But happy to answer your question: the plugin is WP-all-Import.
I think you're saying it's not possible?

Comment: Well, the plugin either lets you pass an array or not. If not, you could modify that behavior possibly.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot GhostToast , I'll look into the plugin

Comment: That is a strange looking shortcode and that functionality looks to be part of the $99 dollar "Pro" version. See: http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-all-import/

Comment: Yup, that's right and I also asked the help of the developer, but still awaiting the answer.

Comment: Meanwhile, within the plugin I found this:

    if (is_dir(self::ROOT_DIR . '/shortcodes')) foreach (PMXI_Helper::safe_glob(self::ROOT_DIR . '/shortcodes/*.php', PMXI_Helper::GLOB_RECURSE | PMXI_Helper::GLOB_PATH) as $filePath) {
    $tag =     strtolower(str_replace('/', '_', preg_replace('%^' . preg_quote(self::ROOT_DIR . '/shortcodes/', '%') . '|\.php$%', '', $filePath)));
    add_shortcode($tag, array($this, 'shortcodeDispatcher'));
    }

Anybody know how to work with the to solve my above problem?